# Perl: should the function TreeBuilder be adapted when it is in a loop foreach?

Tags: perl

My code is to enter an actor name and the program, via the given actor's filmography in IMDB, lists on a hash table all the cinematic genres of the movies he has acted in as well as their frequency. However, I have a problem: When I type a name like "brad pitt" or "bruce willis" after running the program at the prompt, execution takes indefinitely. How do you know what the problem is?

Another problem: when I type "nicolas bedos" (an actor name that I entered from the beginning), it works but it seems that the index is only made for a single movie selected in the @url_links list. Should the look_down function of the TreeBuilder module within a foreach loop be adapted? I was telling myself that the @genres list was overwritten on each iteration so I added a push () but the result remains the same.

```
use LWP::Simple;
use PerlIO::locale;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use WWW::Mechanize;
binmode STDOUT, ':locale';
use strict;
use warnings;


print "Enter the actor's name:";
my $acteur1 = <STDIN>;  # the user enters the name of the actor
print "We will analyze the filmography of the actor $actor1 by genre\n";

#we put the link with the given actor in Mechanize variable in order to browse the internet links
my $lien1 = "https://www.imdb.com/find?s=nm&q=$acteur1";
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get($lien1); #we access the search page with the get function
$mech->follow_link( url_regex => qr/nm0/i ); #we access the first result using the follow_link function and the regular expression nm0 which is in the URL
my @url_links= $mech->find_all_links( url_regex => qr/title\/tt/i ); #owe insert in an array all the links having as regular expression "title" in their URL 
my $nb_links = @url_links; #we record the number of links in the list in this variable

my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new(); #we create the TreeBuilder module to access a specific text on the page via the tags
my %index; #we create a hashing table

my @genres = (); #we create the genre list to insert all the genres encountered
foreach (@url_links) { #we make a loop to browse all the saved links
    my $mech2 = WWW::Mechanize->new();
    my $html = $_->url(); #we take the url of the link
    if ($html =~ m=^/title=) { #if the url starts with "/title"
        $mech2 ->get("https://www.imdb.com$html"); #we complete the link
        my $content = $mech2->content; #we take the content of the page
        $tree->parse($content); #we access the url and we use the tree to find the strings that interest us
        @genres = $tree->look_down ('class', 'see-more inline canwrap', #We have as criterion to access the class = "see-more .."
        sub {
                my $link = $_[0]->look_down('_tag','a'); #new conditions: <a> tags
                $link->attr('href') =~ m{genres=}; #autres conditions: "genres" must be in the URL
        }
        );      
    }       
}   

my @genres1 = (); #we create a new list to insert the words found (the genres of films)
foreach my $e (@genres){ #we create a loop to browse the list
    my $genre = $e->as_text;  #the text of the list element is inserted into the variable
    @genres1 = split(/[à| ]/,$genre); #we remove the unnecessary characters that are spaces, at and | which allow to keep that the terms of genre cine
}

foreach my $e (@genres1){ #another loop to filter listing errors (Genres: etc ..) and add the correct words to the hash table
    if ($e ne ("Genres:" or "") ) {
        $index{$e}++;
    }
}

$tree->delete; #we delete the tree as we no longer need it

foreach my $cle (sort{$index{$b} <=> $index{$a}} keys %index){
    print "$cle : $index{$cle}\n"; #we display the hash table with the genres and the number of times that appear in the filmography of the given actor
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help,
wobot

Answer (score 0):

The [IMDB Conditions of Use](https://www.imdb.com/conditions) say this:

> **Robots and Screen Scraping:** You may not use data mining, robots, screen scraping, or similar data gathering and extraction tools on this site, except with our express written consent as noted below.

So you might want to reconsider what you're doing. Perhaps you could look at the [OMDB API](http://www.omdbapi.com/) instead.